# Generar clave única

Tags: android, firebase

estoy usando firebase firestore y tengo una colección de documentos pero quiero nombrarlos cada uno con una clave única pero sin usar la que me da firebase para Auth porque va a haber más documentos que usuarios. Hay alguna forma de generar una clave única que no se vaya a repetir?
Una forma que se me ocurrió es nombrar cada documento con un numero aleatorio de 0 a 1000000 así disminuyo la posibilidad de que toque el mismo número. Lo malo es que siempre esta la posibilidad de que se repita un número y sobreescribra el documento existente. Algún consejo?

Answer (score 0):

Usar numeros aleatorios es peligroso y no es escalable.

Si usas la base de datos de firebase puedes usar el ID auto generado de la base de datos y asi ya te queda relacionado el id del documento en la base de datos con el id del archivo en firestore.

Si no estas usando la base de datos puedes usar el timestamp de Firestore. Tiene presicion de milisegundos y es virtualmente irrepetible, ya que nunca se va a crear un archivo en firestore en exactamente el mismo milisegundo.

```
 FieldValue uniqueId = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberias usar es el metodo `.add()` que es equivalente al `.push()` en realtime database

Por ejemplo, para guardar un usuario

Kotlin

```
val user = User("Gaston")

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").add(user)
```

Java

```
private User user = new User("Gaston");
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").add(user);
```

Usando `.add()` en vez de `.set()` agrega un nuevo documento con el objeto User pero con un valor alfanumerico aleatorio que es autogenerado con un timestamp